# How do I start a X-application on remote server over ssh?

Tags: x11

I need to start a X program on a remote server over ssh. The program should use the remote X-server (no x-forwarding required). What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
someapp --display <display identifier>
```

or

```
DISPLAY=<display identifier> someapp
```

The display identifier is usually `:0`.

Comment: Make sure you run it as the correct user.

Answer (score 4):

`export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then run your program. you may need to do `xauth +localhost` first. edit: `xhost +localhost` not `xauth`

Comment: Thanks mate!
like 14 years later, still helping people!!
Was wasting over an hour trying to get X11 to work without any success. This was all I needed, since I did not care about seeing the output and just wanted to trigger the app remotely!